# Creating an output json file from list of string objects

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to create an output json (predefined format) from a parsed data which I am getting in a string datatype - I am unable to convert that into required format.

```
import json
name = 'Dojo'
version = '1.1.1'
author = 'Alice'
# For next execution of for loop there will be new values for each variable mentioned above
sample = {'name': name,  'version': version, 'author':author}
d = {"id":"12345",
"Assets":[{'name':value,"version":value,"author":value} for key,value in sample.items()]}     
j = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
print (j)
```

I need to create an output json file in below format -

```
{
  "id" :"12345",
  "Assets" : [{
    "name" : "Dojo",
    "version" : "1.1.1",
    "author" : "Alice",  
  },{
    "name" : "Gogo",
    "version" : "1.2.3",
    "author" : "Bob", 
  }],
}
```

My above code creates a json output which I am not able to fix-

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "Assets": [
        {
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "name": "1.1.1",
            "author": "1.1.1"
        },
        {
            "version": "Dojo",
            "name": "Dojo",
            "author": "Dojo"
        },
        {
            "version": "Alice",
            "name": "Alice",
            "author": "Alice"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct one line:

```
d = {"id":"12345",
"Assets":[{key:value for key,value in sample.items()}]}
```